# how to make SSD and HDD dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a 1TB HDD and 240GB SSD and both have 2 equal partitions. I've installed Windows 10 on one of my SSD drives and want to install Linux on the other. Once the installation completed and I restarted computer. I expected Grub to appear at first and let me choose what OS to boot but it didnt, it instantly boots on Windows 10.[image: it's after installing linux]

I don't know about UEFI but I know it's relevant to this issue, would you explain to me how to solve it?

Comment: Try setting the Ubuntu drive as the first drive, The GRUB bootloader will be on it and Windows should be on it's boot menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dual-booting with a pre-installed Windows 8 but have problems getting a UEFI version of GRUB to work, your OS was not setup/install in UEFI mode. This caused the Ubuntu installer not to recognize Windows and also caused it to install in BIOS mode, meaning the computer will never use it when turning on normally. As a general rule, though, UEFI mode works better in dual-boot setups with pre-installed versions of Windows 8.

### So, What next for you?

**Convert  your ubuntu into UEFI or Legacy mode by**.

- Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.
- If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an UEFI partition (see the "Creating an UEFI partition" paragraph above).
- If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.
- Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in UEFI mode (see the ""Set up the BIOS in UEFI or Legacy mode" paragraph above).

follow the instructions on this link for detailed guidance [Ubuntu in UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_UEFI_mode).

I hope you get it solved ;)